# printing integers and floats but getting 0's

Tags: python

My `macro_percentages` returns a list of 3 ints. I've tested this out and the output is correct. However when I print think out all i am getting are `0.0s` in each of the print statements. There is something causing my values to turn to 0

`macro_percentages --> [20,20,60]`

code:

```
macro_percentages = ask_macro_percentages()
print "Your meal plan consists of: " + str(float((macro_percentages[0]/100) * calorie_deficit)) + "g of protein, ",
print str(float((macro_percentages[1]/100) * calorie_deficit)) + "g of fat, ",
print "and " + str(float((macro_percentages[2]/100) * calorie_deficit)) + "g of carbohydrates"
```

Comment: I assume you are on Python2.x.  You should try either casting your values to float, or dividing by 100.0

Comment: I recommend simply adding this line before starting your calculations: `macro_percentages = [float(value) for value in macro_percentages]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str(float((macro_percentages[0]/100)
```

First, `macro_percentages[0]` is divided by `100`. Because `macro_percentages[0]` is an `int`, and `100` is an `int`, Python 2 uses integer division, giving you `0`. Only after that is the `0` converted to a `float`, and then a `str`. But the fractional value has already been lost by this point.

You can either put this at the top of your script, to use floating point division (the default in Python 3):

```
from __future__ import division
```

Or wrap the float to the numerator:

```
str((float(macro_percentages[0])/100)
```

Or divide by a float `100.0`:

```
str(macro_percentages[0]/100.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When Dividing in Python using integers the value returned will be an integer so all you need to do is change the 100 to 100.0 as so (i substituted 10 for calorie_deficit as i needed to test it) Hope this helps

```
macro_percentages = [20,20,60]

print "Your meal plan consists of: " + str(float((macro_percentages[0]/100.0) * 10)) + "g of protein, ",
print str(float((macro_percentages[1]/100.0) * 10)) + "g of fat, ",
print "and " + str(float((macro_percentages[2]/100.0) * 10)) + "g of carbohydrates"
```